# Expo: Unsupported top level event type "onGestureHandlerStateChange" dispatched

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm working on a React Native application using Expo. I'm trying to use `react-native-gesture-handler`'s `Swipeable` component but I get this error:

[image: Error Message]

There are solutions online that work for earlier versions of RN and this library, but none of them have worked for me. Any help would be much appreciated! My code is below:

This is the implementation of the ListItem component that uses Swipeable:

```
function ListItem({ title, subTitle, image, onPress, renderRightActions }) {
  return (
    <Swipeable renderRightActions={renderRightActions}>
      <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={colors.light} onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={image} />
          <View>
            <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
            <AppText style={styles.subTitle}>{subTitle}</AppText>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </Swipeable>
  );
}
```

This is the Screen that uses the ListItem

```
function MessagesScreen(props) {
    return (
        <Screen>
            <FlatList 
                data={messages}
                keyExtractor={message => message.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ListItem 
                        title={item.title}
                        subTitle={item.description}
                        image={item.image}
                        onPress={() => console.log('Message selected', item)}
                        renderRightActions={() => (
                            <View 
                                style={{
                                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                                    width: 70,
                                }}
                            ></View>
                        )}
                    />
                )}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
            />
        </Screen>
    );
}
```

I've tried importing `react-native-gesture-handler` at my app's entry point so it is imported before its first usage, and I've also tried wrapping the `Swipeable` component with the `GestureHandlerRootView` component as well. None have worked, and the error persists.

Comment: Did you install `react-native-gesture-handler` with `npm` or `npx expo` ?

Comment: First with npm and then re-tried with npx expo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after I updated my `expo-constants` package to the latest version.